# jQuery: form serialize, hidden fields, and not displayed fields

Tags: jquery, forms, serialization, hidden

I am using `$(this).serialize()` when submitting a form.

It works well, except in times when I (for some reason) have 2 fields with same name (one visible, and one not, and I am not talking about `type="visible"` but `display:none`)...

But of course `serialize` has no regard for this... it just takes them all.

I tried this

```
var $disabled_list = $(this).find('input:hidden,select:hidden,textarea:hidden').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$(this).serialize();
$disabled_list.attr('disabled','');
```

and It is solving my problem, except the :hidden selector, takes also type="hidden"

what's the proper way?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You do not have to call `serialize()` on the `<form>` itself, you can match some of its controls and call it on the resulting set. This allows you to avoid tinkering with `disabled` attributes.

Since you want controls matching `:hidden` only if they also actually expose the `hidden` type, you can use the following selector:

```
$(this).find("input[type='hidden'], :input:not(:hidden)").serialize();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use $form.find(':visible').serialize()

Answer (score 0):

```
var $disabled_list = $(this).find('input:hidden,select:hidden,textarea:hidden').not('input[type=hidden]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

tried this way and it seems to work